# Update Vue Router without remounting components?

Tags: vue.js

I have a page that inherits an `activeTab` routing param from the URL path.  So on my page, I can navigate to `/home/` and load in the home tab, or at `/somethingElse` I can load in a different tab within my page template's tab viewport.

To update the tab, I'm using:

```
updateTab(tab) {
  this.activeTab = tab
  this.$router.push(tab)
}
```

When I do this, I get a flicker across the screen, and my `mounted()` functions are re-executed across every component, triggering an animation that should only be triggered on the application's first entry point.

This comes closer to the desired behavior, where the tab changes and I don't get a flicker or remounting of the components:

```
updateTab(tab) {
  this.activeTab = tab
  history.pushState({}, '', tab)
}
```

However, pushing the activeTab directly into the history seems to prevent the Back button from correctly restoring the previous state.

How can I update the path at the Vue Router without remounting all of my components?

Comment: On which browser are you testing and what plugins are enabled? This sounds like a compatibility fallback, or, like Joachim answered: some other component rerenders your page. Often found in complex layouts with minor mistakes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not the expected behaviour. Components that do not change should not re-execute the mounted hook.

I would search for the problem someplace in the top of the vue component hierarchy, because it sounds like some other piece of code might force the re-rendering of the hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me at the right direction with this answer. My problem was that the RouterView component was using `route.fullPath` as key in my App.vue which caused every component to remount.

Answer (score 4):

When router's path changes, components will mount again,if you want to mount component only one time, you can try the Vue's build-in component **keep-alive**, it will only trigger its activated hook and deactivated hook.And you can do something in these two hooks.

**The html:**

```
<div id="app">
      <router-link to="/link-one">link-one</router-link>
      <router-link to="/link-two">link-two</router-link>
       <keep-alive>
         <router-view>

         </router-view>
       </keep-alive>
 </div>
```

---

**The javascript:**

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);
        function createLink(path) {
            let routePath = '/' + path;
            return {
                path: routePath,
                component: {
                    name: path,
                    template: '<span>{{path}} mountedTimes:{{mountedTimes}}, activatedTimes: {{activatedTimes}}</span>',
                    data() {
                        return {
                            mountedTimes: 0,
                            activatedTimes: 0,
                            path: routePath
                        }
                    },
                    mounted() {
                      console.log('mounted')
                        this.mountedTimes++;
                    },
                    activated() {
                        this.activatedTimes++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        const routes = [createLink('link-one'), createLink('link-two')];
        const router = new VueRouter({
            routes
        })
        const app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            router
        })
```

---

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/wangyi7099/pen/OvVaQr)